# Expand definition of range, ie add more columns to a already defined range

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to figure out if there is a smooth and easy way to expand a range to try and simplify coding.

For example say that you have a range that you want to apply some formatting to, and then apply another formatting to that range but also include two more columns, and then include two more before you create a named range from the entire range.

Maybe one would want to include some kind of IF statements or whatever between each expansion of the range.

I kind of expected there to be a method like

```
range.expandRange(numOfRows,numOfColumns)
```

that redefines the range.
o if you have

```
let range = ss.getRange("A3:G6);
range.expandRange(3,5);
console.log(range.getA1Notation());
```

the result would be "A3:L9"

Does anyone have any idea how this can be accomplished in a easy way?

Just for completeness sake, the reason I got stuck on this idea is because of this code:

```
      if(lastf-firstf > 0){
        let formrange = paramsheet.getRange(2,firstf,paramsheet.getLastRow(),lastf-firstf+1);
        paramsheet.getRange(2,firstf,1,lastf-firstf+1).copyTo(formrange);
        console.log(formrange.getA1Notation());
        ssNew.setNamedRange(sanitizedParameter + "formulas", formrange);
      }
```

Where I have formulas in a template sheet that I copy and then insert data into. The template contains several sheet with formulas that calculate different parameters. The code above copies the formula from the first row and pastes it to every row that has data. It then names this range so I can reference the result from the calculations on another sheet. The issue is that on some sheets there is also an array formula that does not need to be copied but it should be included in the namedRange.
So really what I am after is some way to expand the "formrange" (formula range) to also include the result from the array formula when creating the namedRange.

I hope all of this makes sense. If it doesn't, I blame the fact that it is friday evening when I type this.
Thanks y'all

Comment: Use the getRange() method that accepts four parameters.  The fourth parameter is the number of columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have to redefine the range.  Here is an example.

I have a named range "TestRange" as shown.

[image]

Using the following script I expand the range.

**Code.gs**

```
function expandRange() {
  let ranges = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getNamedRanges();
  ranges.some( range => {
      if( range.getName() === "TestRange" ) {
        range.setRange(range.getRange().offset(0,0,3,2)); // A2:B4
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  );
}
```

Notice the named range is expanded.

[image]

**Refernce**

- [Spreadsheet.getNamedRanges()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getNamedRanges())
- [NamedRange.setRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/named-range#setRange(Range))

Comment: Thank you! 
The getRange().offset(r,c,rs,cs) is exactly what I wanted!